# Stack Exchange JavaScript is taking much longer to load than usual

Tags: bug, javascript, performance

After the recent SE network outage, I noticed that the JavaScript that powers things like the vote buttons, the dropdowns, and the "add comment" button takes *much* longer to load than it did in the past. This means a much increased period of time when clicking certain buttons will simply add a `#` sign to the end of the URL (unexpectedly scrolling pages to the top, and preventing links from oneboxing in chat - not sure if that's intentional or a bug), and clicking certain things in the top bar will send people straight to a link rather than opening a dropdown (e.g. the Stack Exchange logo, or the review icon). It's also taking a few seconds for the review "busy" dots to show up, whereas it used to happen pretty much instantaneously.

Just a few hours ago, all those scripts used to load snappily. However, after the recent outage, it's all of a sudden taking much longer to load on my end. What happened that caused them to be served so slowly?

Comment: Hmm... cannot reproduce it all, everything working smooth as always here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could be region-specific.

Comment: To close voters: I can still reproduce the issue. This should not be voted for closure as "can no longer be reproduced".

Comment: Are you sure the latency isn't on your side? It works fine with me, and I'm using a VPN.

Comment: I actually did encounter this often before the outage. Hasn't happened since but anecdotal evidence and all.

Comment: I see this every once in a while on Stack Apps.  Very hard to reproduce and I only rarely click something immediately on/after page load, so it's not too annoying.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog can you still reproduce this?

Comment: @MEEthesneakyuser Sort of, it's running about 50% faster but still slow compared to the past. May have something to do with the change to Typescript; that resulted in a lot of JS bugs.